# How to call the api once for each request instead of twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server-side-rendering

I am calling the api twice. Once for rendering the frontend and other time for displaying the data. How should i perform both the operations with 1 api call?

```
route.get("/update-user", (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:3000/api/users", { params: { id: req.query.id } })
    .then(function (userdata) {
      res.render("update_user", { user: userdata.data });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});

//api call
route.put("/api/users/:id", (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: "Data to update can not be empty" });
    }
  
    const id = req.params.id;
    Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false })
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          res.status(404).send({
            message: `Cannot Update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`,
          });
        } else {
          res.send(data);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error Update user information" });
      });
  });
```

Comment: your question is quite confusing
server side API method is put but you are calling APIs by get and why do you need to call twice
First you will call get API to display data
If user update anything then you will call update API it will also return you updated data just set that data.

Comment: which Endpoint called twice? according to the code, there's nothing wrong with it. thats how API works. => https://www.ibm.com/topics/api

Comment: I'm guessing (based on my knowledge of... things, it's absolutely unclear from your question) that you're using React and your component is making two requests to the backend. If that's true please share your frontend code.